# Quantum Mechanics- Spin

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, spin-geometry

I start saying I'm Italian, so my English is not very well and I will probably make many grammar mistakes ( forgive me for that)...

I have to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this Hamiltonian described by two particles of spin $1 \over 2 $:

$\hat{H} = A (\hat S_{1y} - \hat S_{2y})^2$, where $A$ is a real constant.

All the problems I solved till now presented Hamiltonian with explicit ( or easy implicit) $\hat J_z $ and $\hat J^2$ dependency.

I think I can say that a basis of total Hilbert space  $\hat V_1 \times \hat V_2$ is :

$|1/2 ,1/2\rangle|1/2 ,1/2\rangle,\  |1/2 ,1/2\rangle|1/2 ,-1/2\rangle,\ |1/2 ,-1/2\rangle|1/2 ,1/2\rangle,\ |1/2 ,-1/2\rangle|1/2 ,-1/2\rangle$.

The text of the problem also remembers me the expression of annihilator/construction operators $\hat J_\pm$ .

How can I solve this kind of problem without finding the form of both matrices? does it exist an easier way? Thanks in advance, I'm new to Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Does the question specify which basis you are to construct the eigenstates in? If not, then you can check that your basis states are actually eigenstates of $H$ by directly applying $H$ to them

Comment: @Sal  if they are  actually eigenstates how can I determine eingenvalues since $H$ has just dependency of $S_y$ ?

Comment: The $S_1$ operator acts only on particle 1, and the $S_2$ operator only acts on particles 2. Choose eigenstates of $S_y$ (rather than $S_z$) for both particles, the states are still labelled by $y_\pm$ and still have eigenvalues $\pm 1/2$

Comment: Mathematical, the problem is trivial, and it should have been posted in the PSE, where anyone is  unequivocally  familiar with the language...